# Extracting a part of a string using R

Tags: r, regex, string

I need to extract a part of the string that staring from a certain pattern and ends with another pattern.

My code is as follows:

```
library(stringr)    
s1="Ben Fisher5.0 out of 5 stars\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n \n Purchased 2, one had a quality issue but they sent a replacement\n \nReviewed in the United States <U+0001F1FA><U+0001F1F8>"
    
    start_pattern <- "out of 5 stars\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n \n"
    end_pattern <- "<U+0001F1FA>" 
    
    str_extract(s1, paste0("(?<=", start_pattern, ").*(?=",end_pattern  , ")"))
```

But this code give the output as `NA`

Could anyone suggest anything to get the correct result?. I need to get the final output as "Purchased 2, one had a quality issue but they sent a replacement\n \nReviewed in the United States"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may have to capture one or more characters that are not `<` with `([^<]+)`) instead of just `(.*)`.  The prefix (`out of 5 stars[\n\\s]+`) matches the substring with one or more spaces and the next line character and the suffix matches one or more spaces followed by the specific string U+0001F1FA.  The `+` is escaped as it can be a metacharacter in regex mode (`\\s+<U\\+0001F1FA`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(s1, "out of 5 stars[\n\\s]+([^<]+)\\s+<U\\+0001F1FA", group = 1)
```

-output

```
[1] "Purchased 2, one had a quality issue but they sent a replacement\n \nReviewed in the United States"
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Is it possible to explain your code? (How you decided the terms for the regular expression)

Comment: @student_R123 i added some details. Hope it helps